# URL encoding IE8 vs Firefox/Chrome for UTF8 characters

Tags: php, firefox, internet-explorer-8

In Firefox, an URL with special characters, like `é`, goes to

`stores.php?id=AsuntosClientes&ancesterComboValue=Pérez, Gabriel&limit=25`,

in IE8, it goes to

`stores.php?id=AsuntosClientes&ancesterComboValue=P%C3%A9rez,%20Gabriel&limit=25`,

In PHP, with IE8, the $_GET entry is `string(14) "P�rez, Gabriel"`

With Firefox, it is: `string(15) "Pérez, Gabriel"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do:

```
if( ! mb_detect_encoding($_GET['ancesterComboValue'], 'UTF-8', true) ){
  $_GET['ancesterComboValue'] = utf8_encode($_GET['ancesterComboValue']);
}
```

We have to check first if the string is not in UTF8 already, otherway we encode it from CP1252 to UTF8.

If we would not check for it, then it would break in Firefox, because it will re-encode an already UTF8 encoded string, and it will look like `string(17) "PÃ©rez, Gabriel"`.